Code inside LaunchedEffect throws the following exception : "The coroutine scope left the composition"
I have the following UI structure :
Parent Lazy Column :
TvLazyColumn(){
    itemsIndexed(rows){index, row ->
        MyLazyRow(mainViewModel, row, index)
    }
}

MyLazyRow.kt :
@Composable
fun MyLazyRow(mainViewModel : MainViewModel, row : List<rowItem>, listIndex : Int){
    val myLazyState = rememberTvLazyListState()
    val myRequesters by remember(row.size) { derivedStateOf { Array(row.size) { FocusRequester() } } }
    TvLazyRow(state = myLazyState){
        itemsIndexed(row){ index, rowItem ->
            MyItem(item = rowItem, modifier = Modifier.focusRequester(myRequesters[index]))
        }
    }
    LaunchedEffect(Unit){
        if (listIndex == mainViewModel.getLastFocussedRow.value){
            try {
                myLazyState.scrollToItem(dummyTargetFocus) //some randomly set const val
                myRequesters[dummyTargetFocus].requestFocus()
            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                ex.printStackTrace()
            }
        }  
    }
}

As can be seen in the code, I am trying to get focus to a random card which is in one of the LazyRow(s), however when the code inside LaunchedEffect() runs, it throws the same error :

androidx.compose.runtime.LeftCompositionCancellationException: The
coroutine scope left the composition

Even after making sure that the composable which we are requesting focus to : (Both lazy row and item) are on the screen and have been composed at the time of the focus request. What might be the cause of this error, and can I have any other workarounds to this problem?

Does this help?

Can you also add the entire stacktrace?

Got the same error in Column with verticalScroll(). @rahul-rawat Anything updates?

This exception just means that the coroutine scope was cancelled because the LaunchedEffect was removed from "screen". Basically if the row is recycled because it's no longer visible, the coroutine scope to the LaunchedEffect is cancelled. This is the expected behavior as you don't want a UI element to start a background task that lives longer than the UI element itself.
If this is something you want, you can also use rememberCoroutineScope() outside of your LazyColumn, this scope stays active until this part of the UI is removed but will not be stopped when a row is recycled. You could do something like this, but that takes away a lot of benefits of LaunchedEffect:
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
LazyList {
   item {
      SideEffect {
         scope.launch {
            ...
         }
      }
   }
}

Your code implies you want the work to be cancelled, but the error message shows up in the logs. You can do the following, which is totally fine as the CancellationException just ends the coroutine execution and will not cause a crash.
try {
   ...
} catch (e: CancellationException) {
   // Ignore
} catch (e: Exception) {
   ...
}

